# Adding Scope Bar in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

The app shows a list of cars parts (car part, type, year, country) it is working in a tableview with a search bar.

Now I decided to add a scope bar to filter the results, and I am sure I messed up with the code. There are many errors in the lines to add the scopeBar. It is the last 20 lines, after the comment `//ScopeBar try`, other than this last lines I added a code in the `viewDidLoad()` to show the titles I want.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is more than welcome, I am trying to fix this for 2 days already no luck.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DictionaryTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating
{

    var searchController:UISearchController!
    var searchResults:[Dictionary] = []

    private var dictionaryItems:[Dictionary] = []

    private var cockpitDict = [String: [Dictionary]]()
    var sectionTitles = [String]()

    var fetchResultController:NSFetchedResultsController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // ScopeBar Try
        searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "type", "year", "country"]
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar



        // Load menu items from database
        if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {

            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "DictionaryEntity")
            do {
                dictionaryItems = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Dictionary]
            } catch {
                print("Failed to retrieve record")
                print(error)
            }
        }

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search ..."

        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style:
            .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)

        // Enable self sizing cells
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension


        createCockpitDict()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func createCockpitDict(){

        for item in dictionaryItems {

            guard let word = item.word else {
                break
            }

            // Get the first letter of the word and build the dictionary
            let wordKey = word.substringToIndex(word.startIndex.advancedBy(1))
            if var cockpitItems = cockpitDict[wordKey] {
                cockpitItems.append(item)
                cockpitDict[wordKey] = cockpitItems
            } else {
                cockpitDict[wordKey] = [item]
            }
        }

        // Get the section titles from the dictionary's keys and sort them in ascending order
        sectionTitles = [String](cockpitDict.keys)
        sectionTitles = sectionTitles.sort({ $0 < $1 })
    }

//    create a standard way to get a Dictionary from a index path
    func itemForIndexPath (indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Dictionary? {
        var result: Dictionary? = nil

        if searchController.active {
            result = searchResults[indexPath.row]
        }else{
            let wordKey = sectionTitles[indexPath.section]
            if let items = cockpitDict[wordKey]{
                result = items[indexPath.row]
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sectionTitles[section]
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        //assume a single section after a search
        return (searchController.active) ? 1 : sectionTitles.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if searchController.active {
            return searchResults.count
        } else {
            // Return the number of rows in the section.
            let wordKey = sectionTitles[section]
            if let items = cockpitDict[wordKey] {
                return items.count
            }

            return 0
        }
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DictionaryTableViewCell

        //let dictionary = (searchController.active) ? searchResults[indexPath.row]: dictionaryItems[indexPath.row]
        if let dictionary = itemForIndexPath(indexPath){
            cell.wordLabel.text = dictionary.word
            cell.definitionSmallLabel.text =  dictionary.definition
            cell.typeLabel.text = dictionary.type
            cell.yearLabel.text = dictionary.year
            cell.countryLabel.text = dictionary.country


        }else{
            print("Cell error with path\(indexPath)")
        }
            return cell
    }

    override func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return sectionTitles
    }

    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        if searchController.active{
            return false
        }else{
            return true
        }
    }

     override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDictionaryDetail" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! DictionaryDetailViewController
                if let dictionary = itemForIndexPath(indexPath){
                    destinationController.dictionary = dictionary
                }else{
                    print("Segue error with path \(indexPath)")
                }
                searchController.active = false
            }
        }
    }

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
            if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {
                filterContentForSearchText(searchText)
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
    }

    func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {
        searchResults = dictionaryItems.filter({ (dictionary:Dictionary) -> Bool in
            let wordMatch = dictionary.word!.rangeOfString(searchText, options:
                NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
            return wordMatch != nil
        })
    }    
}

//ScopeBar try: all lines below got many errors I can not figure out how to fix it :(

func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    dictionaryItems = cockpitDict.filter({( cockpitDict : Dictionary) -> Bool in
        let categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (cockpitDict.category == scope)
        return categoryMatch && cockpitDict.name.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)
    })
    tableView.reloadData()
}

extension DictionaryTableViewController:UISearchBarDelegate {
    // MARK: - UISearchBar Delegate
    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchBar.text!, scope: searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![selectedScope])
    }
}

extension DictionaryTableViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    // MARK: - UISearchResultsUpdating Delegate
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
        let scope = searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex]
        filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!, scope: scope)
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Swift are you using? Even `var searchResults:[Dictionary] = []` doesn't compile for me. Perhaps the first step is to update to the current version of Swift.

Comment: @ Dave Batton my xcode version is 7.2.1(7C1002) the last version available.

Comment: @Jade you for sure won't get the reason why your code doesn't work, as it does not even get compiled. Fix your compiler errors, and then we can see what is wrong with your code

Comment: I don't believe that having the latest version of Xcode is the same as using the latest version of Swift. Do you see a compiler warning telling you to upgrade to the latest version of Swift or to update your project settings?

Comment: No the compiler does not ask for update. :(

Comment: What is the list of scope and on which param you want scope to be classified?

Comment: @Jade please check and let me know if you need any change
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35942436/2963912

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went through whole code provided in github and resolved it

Change your viewDidLoad to

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Load menu items from database
        if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext {

            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "DictionaryEntity")
            do {
                dictionaryItems = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Dictionary]
            } catch {
                print("Failed to retrieve record")
                print(error)
            }
        }

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search ..."

// you were setting before initialization
        searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "type", "year", "country"]

        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style:
            .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)

        // Enable self sizing cells
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension


        createCockpitDict()
    }
```

and For last scopebar filtering

```
func filterContentForSearchText(var searchText: String, scope: NSInteger) {


searchText = searchText.lowercaseString;

func checkString(strData: String, strSearchData: String)-> Bool{
   return strData.rangeOfString(strSearchData, options:
        NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil
}

searchResults = dictionaryItems.filter({ (dictionary:Dictionary) -> Bool in

    switch scope {
    case 0:
        return (checkString(dictionary.word!, strSearchData: searchText) || checkString(dictionary.type!, strSearchData: searchText) || checkString(dictionary.country!, strSearchData: searchText) || checkString(dictionary.year!, strSearchData: searchText))
    case 1:
        return checkString(dictionary.type!, strSearchData: searchText)
    case 2:
        return checkString(dictionary.year!, strSearchData: searchText)
    case 3:
        return checkString(dictionary.country!, strSearchData: searchText)
    default:
        return true;
    }

})

tableView.reloadData()

}


// MARK: - UISearchBar Delegate
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchBar.text!, scope: searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex)
}



// MARK: - UISearchResultsUpdating Delegate - comment older method so duplicate method error will be vanished
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
    filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!, scope: searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex)
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the correction, I am still getting three errors in the scope bar filtering: searchResults = dictionaryItems.filter({..... = use of unresolved identifier 'searchResults' & 'dictionaryItems'  + in line: tableView.reloadData()  = use of unresolved identifier 'tableView". Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Hey you must be adding this out of class bracket, check it

Comment: Because u put it outside of the class I checked and ran your code

Comment: See in your question, u have added this method out of scope

Comment: I just started a chat maybe it is better :) http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106113/scopebar

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues with this code. For starters, as others have pointed out, `var searchResults:[Dictionary] = []` isn't valid syntax. A `Dictionary` in Swift requires a type specification, such as `Dictionary<String: AnyObject>`. I'm guessing based off the rest of your code that you've named a custom entity named `Dictionary`, which may be causing the confusion.

The next issue I see is that on lines 8 and 10, you need to initialize the array, using `()`, i.e. `var searchResults:[Dictionary] = []()`. (Again, this is assuming you fix the issue of declaring your `Dictionary` type correctly.)

Another issue is your `filter` statement on line 192:

```
dictionaryItems = cockpitDict.filter({( cockpitDict : Dictionary) -> Bool in
    let categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (cockpitDict.category == scope)
    return categoryMatch && cockpitDict.name.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)
})
```

Let's take a look at the definition of `cockpitDict` on line 12:

```
private var cockpitDict = [String: [Dictionary]]()
```

Because this is an `Array` with a `String` key and an `Array<Dictionary>` value, you have both a `key` and `value` to capture in the closure. The filter statement needs to be different, something like this (again, I've made some assumptions on the definition of your custom `Dictionary` type):

```
dictionaryItems = cockpitDict.filter({(key, value) -> Bool in
    let categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (value.category == scope)
    return categoryMatch && value.name.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)
})
```